# java getBytes error

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am using ZXing library for my application and I use [this](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/datamatrix/encoder/Base256Encoder.java?spec=svn2800&r=2800) class.
But when I run my application I have en error on this line:

```
String msg = "123456";
byte[] msgBinary = msg.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

And the error is below:

```
java: no suitable method found for getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)
    method java.lang.String.getBytes(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.nio.charset.Charset cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion)
    method java.lang.String.getBytes(int,int,byte[],int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.lang.String.getBytes() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem here I checked that getBytes input parameteres only is String (getBytes(java.lang.String encoding)) but Charset.forName return Charset.
What is the problem in here?

Comment: The `getBytes(Charset)` method is only available from API level 9.

Comment: Try using the `getBytes(String)` one, it's there since API level 1. Simply call `getBytes("ISO-8591-1")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Code Painters alludes to, the core library and Android app are written assuming Java 6 and Android API level 10 (aka Gingerbread / Android 2.3.3). If you target an earlier version of Java, or Android, it may not work. You can either target API 10+ (or at least 9) or modify the code to not use methods that were added after the API level you support.

(There are a few more surprising gotchas. Look at when `String.isEmpty()` and `new IOException(Throwable)` -- both standard Java 6 methods -- were added to Android. In reality, Android started out somewhere between Java 5 and 6 and is only recently compatible with Java 6's standard lib)

Comment: Good call.  `String.isEmpty()` is something I kept trying to use with Android 2.2, and it just wasn't in there.  The documentation suggested that it should have been, but it wasn't.